# matchesInString function returning an empty Array in Swift

Tags: regex, swift

I have this code working in Objective-C

```
NSRegularExpression* regex = [[NSRegularExpression alloc] initWithPattern:@"(.*?)(<[^>]+>|\\Z)" options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive|NSRegularExpressionDotMatchesLineSeparators error:nil];
NSArray* results = [regex matchesInString:text options:NSMatchingReportProgress range:NSMakeRange(0, text.length)];
```

But the Swift version is not working. The `matchesInString` is returning an empty `Array` (using the same tagged text in both cases)

```
let regexOptions = NSRegularExpressionOptions.CaseInsensitive | NSRegularExpressionOptions.DotMatchesLineSeparators
let regex = NSRegularExpression.regularExpressionWithPattern("(.*?)(<[^>]+>|\\Z)", options: regexOptions, error: nil)
var results = regex.matchesInString(markupText, options: nil, range: NSMakeRange(0, countElements(markupText))) as Array<NSTextCheckingResult>
```

Even though the documentation states that the `matchesInString` returns an `Array` of `NSTextCheckingResult`, I noted that in the Objective-C code (that works) the `Array` contains `NSSimpleRegularExpressionCheckingResult` objects and not `NSTextCheckingResult` objects. The empty `Array` reported in the Swift version reports zero `NSTextCheckingResult` objects though

Any idea of what is missing here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Update**, this works for me:

```
let regexOptions:NSRegularExpressionOptions?
    = NSRegularExpressionOptions.CaseInsensitive

var matchingError : NSError?
let regex = NSRegularExpression(pattern: "(.*?)(<[^>]+>|\\Z)",
    options: regexOptions!, error: &matchingError)

let markupText = "<html></html>"

let results = regex.matchesInString(markupText, options: nil,
    range: NSMakeRange(0, countElements(markupText))) as Array<NSTextCheckingResult>
```

I am not sure why regexOptions has to be an optional. May be a bug in the compiler.

*Older thoughts*

This may be a bug in Xcode6b2. I simplified your example to just one line:

```
let regexOptions = NSRegularExpressionOptions.CaseInsensitive
```

And I get this error:

```
fatal error: Can't unwrap Optional.None
```

I would file a bug for this.

Comment: Thx for the reply... It now works...  It seems that Swift is still evolving and things are fine tuned as we speak