# Matching a bunch of strings within a given string via Regex

Tags: ios, objective-c, regex

I have a scenario in which I have a string which seems like -

```
"Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. \n\nLorem Ipsum has been the industry's \n\nstandard dummy text ever since the 1500s.when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book."
```

I want to retrieve the line `"Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s."` and make it as italic. So I embedded the complete sentence in an square braces as below and create a Regex and do as follows -

*I do not want to calculate manually the range for which I am doing so.*

```
"Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. \n\n[Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's \n\nstandard dummy text ever since the 1500s].when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book."
```

And wrote the following code for retrieving so -

```
NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"\\[(.*?)\\]" options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive error:NULL];

    NSArray *myArray = [regex matchesInString:testString options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [testString length])] ;//testString is my concerned String

    NSMutableArray *matches = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:[myArray count]];

    for (NSTextCheckingResult *match in myArray) {
        NSRange matchRange = [match rangeAtIndex:1];
        [matches addObject:[testString substringWithRange:matchRange]];
        NSLog(@"%@", [matches lastObject]);
    }
```

***Now I am being able to retrieve the block if I am not using any new line syntax(i.e when I remove \n). But when \n is there it is not retrieving the same.***

So what might be the issue.

Comment: Usually the dot `.` won't match newlines `\n` unless the _Dot-All_ flag is set as a regex option. Try to OR the option into this `options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive|<here>`

Comment: Why would you have newlines in the middle of sentence?

Comment: @rmaddy Actually this is an example and in my case I need to have multiple lines which are a new lines rather than in same string.

Comment: @sln can you please elaborate in an answer.

Comment: I elaborated in an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Sure.

(
see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24344697/matchesinstring-function-returning-an-empty-array-in-swift) post as well.
If the below *option* doesn't work, change the regex to this
`:@"\\[([\\S\\s]*?)\\]"`
)

You don't really need the `CaseInsensitive` option
since your regex does not reference letters specifically.

I think the default is the dot matches any character but newline.

From **[here](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Foundation.NSRegularExpressionOptions/)** it says this is so called *Dot-All* option.

`DotMatchesLineSeparators`

which allows the dot to match newlines as well.

Since it's an enum, might want to append `NSRegularExpressionOptions.` to it.

Comment: Note this is with Xamarin, and I don't know if it's the same thing you're using.